# map method not working at some place using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, conditional-statements

I have Output in JSON format and i want to specific field from it

```
{
 "id":"01",
 "name":"fish",
 "Data.id":"f01",
 "Data.path":"/home/work/fish.jpg"
}
```

I am using map function to get the value but the problem is i can only fetch the value of `id and name` not `Data.id and Data.path`

- so i am getting this value from my database and this is my code by how i am getting the value from database

```js
function runRest(req, res) {
    let data = req.body;
    Owner.findAll({
      raw: true,
      where: {
        id: data.id,
      },
      include: {
        model: kingdom,
        required: false,
      },

      attributes: ["id", "name"],
    })
      .then((parents) => {

        parents.map((value) => {
          console.log(value);
        });

      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
}
```

```js
let value={
 "id":"01",
 "name":"fish",
 "Data.id":"f01",
 "Data.path":"/home/work/fish.jpg"
};


value.map((data)=>{
console.log(data.id);
});
```

I can only fetch data which is in white font color which is ID and name any solution how can i get Data.id and Data.path by using map function

[image]

I even tried this

```js
let links = value
                .map((child) => {
                   for (let i in child)
                     if (i === "Data.id") {
                       return child[i];
                     }
                 })
```

but i don't want to use this for method any chance I can use Map function ?

Comment: Why do you want to use `map`? That's an array method but you don't have an array here, only an object. The props you want are just strings; `value["Data.id"]`. Both the object variable "value" and these props are confusingly named. Your code snippet crashes with `TypeError: value.map is not a function`, so I'm not sure how this is working for you in any environment. Maybe you've only shown a single entry of the `value` array. In that case, try `whateverYourArrayReallyIs.map(e => e["Data.id"])`.

Comment: Hello @ggorlen this data is fetched from my database in form of object and there are more then this single data and i want to get all the Data.name from all my output but cant fetch it

Comment: its working fine here but i dont know why its not working here @ggorlen

Comment: Hello @ggorlen I have updated my question i hope its now understandable

Comment: Try `parents.map(e => e["Data.id"])`. If that doesn't work, please post the error and use `JSON.stringify(parents, null, 2)` and copy-paste the output here. I don't have your database so the code doesn't do me much good since I can't run it, but I appreciate the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object

```
values = {
 "id":"01",
 "name":"fish",
 "Data.id":"f01",
 "Data.path":"/home/work/fish.jpg"
};
```

Has the keys: `"id", "name", "Data.id", "Data.path"`

To get the value `"f01"` you must use the key "Data.id":

```
foo = values["Data.id"]; // foo === "f01"
```

In the comments you mention that you want to map an array of these objects to the data id:

```
idArray = objects.map(value => value["Data.id"]);
```

Comment: there are more values as i am fetching this data from my database

Comment: @Vikas yes I updated based on your comment